# How to convert list of list to list of objects in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3.7. I have an array of arrays:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

How can I make it become an array of objects?

```
[
{
name:1,
surname:2,
price:3,
location:4
},
{
name:5,
surname:6,
price:7,
location:8
},
{
name:9,
surname:10,
price:11,
location:12
}
]
```

I tried to use

```
array=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
json_str = json.dumps(array)
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Why *would* that work? `json.dumps` just creates a JSON string of whatever you pass it, it doesn't transform anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks that's very helpful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we read the documentation of [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str using this conversion table.

Which is not what we want. We want to transform your list of lists to a list of dictionaries, where the keys `['name', 'surname', 'price', 'location']` are zipped with each sub list.

An easy solution would be to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) inside a *list comprehension*:

```
lst =  [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]] 

keys = ['name', 'surname', 'price', 'location']

print([dict(zip(keys, sublst)) for sublst in lst])
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 1, 'surname': 2, 'price': 3, 'location': 4}, {'name': 5, 'surname': 6, 'price': 7, 'location': 8}, {'name': 9, 'surname': 10, 'price': 11, 'location': 12}]
```

**Note:** This assumes the zipped lists are of equal length. Otherwise we can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to zip uneven length lists.

Comment: this is beautiful

Comment: @emiljoj that's just the plain simple and obvious pythonic way - welcome to Python ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**input**

```
a = ["AB", "corona"]
b = ["india",'openVINO']
c = ["korea"]
d = ["26", "10.mp3", "Nvidia.mp4"]
e = ["washington DC",6]
f = ['swiss']

import itertools

lst = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
# print(lst)
lsts = list(itertools.product(*lst))
for lst in lsts:
  print('\n')
  for con in lst:
    print(con)
```

**output**

```
AB
india
korea
26
washington DC
swiss


AB
india
korea
26
6
swiss


AB
india
korea
10.mp3
washington DC
swiss


AB
india
korea
10.mp3
6
swiss


AB
india
korea
Nvidia.mp4
washington DC
swiss


AB
india
korea
Nvidia.mp4
6
swiss


AB
openVINO
korea
26
washington DC
swiss


AB
openVINO
korea
26
6
swiss


AB
openVINO
korea
10.mp3
washington DC
swiss


AB
openVINO
korea
10.mp3
6
swiss


AB
openVINO
korea
Nvidia.mp4
washington DC
swiss


AB
openVINO
korea
Nvidia.mp4
6
swiss


corona
india
korea
26
washington DC
swiss


corona
india
korea
26
6
swiss


corona
india
korea
10.mp3
washington DC
swiss


corona
india
korea
10.mp3
6
swiss


corona
india
korea
Nvidia.mp4
washington DC
swiss


corona
india
korea
Nvidia.mp4
6
swiss


corona
openVINO
korea
26
washington DC
swiss


corona
openVINO
korea
26
6
swiss


corona
openVINO
korea
10.mp3
washington DC
swiss


corona
openVINO
korea
10.mp3
6
swiss


corona
openVINO
korea
Nvidia.mp4
washington DC
swiss


corona
openVINO
korea
Nvidia.mp4
6
swiss
```

Answer (score -1):

Judging from the output you have given as an example, I am guessing that you are looking to create a **list of dictionaries**. Following script should grant your the output saved as new_list

```
array=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
new_list = []
for element in array:
    temp_dict = {}
    for x in element:
        if element.index(x) == 0:
            temp_str = 'name'
        elif element.index(x) == 1:
            temp_str = 'surname'
        elif element.index(x) == 2:
            temp_str = 'price'
        elif element.index(x) == 3:
            temp_str = 'location'
        temp_dict[temp_str] = x
    new_list.append(temp_dict)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: `list.index` gives the *first* index for a given value, so this is very fragile. It's also quite difficult to read.

Comment: point taken, given the use case it's the simplest that worked for me, I guess https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate can be used in the second loop. what do you suggest?

Comment: I think the `zip` approach in the other answer makes most sense, you can see the structure of the keys in one place. Enumerate would be a little neater, and doesn't have the issue with multiple appearances of the same value.